# XNA / MonoGame: depth sorting alpha blended UserPrimitives

Tags: xna, primitive, alphablending, depth, monogame

Googling around a lot for this, read [this very useful article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/02/18/depth-sorting-alpha-blended-objects.aspx), but still wondering about a solution for my project. This screenshot illustrates my problem perfectly:

[image: Alpha Blend Problem]

There are 2 objects: the red object which consists of 2 quads, one with z-index of -1 and the other one with a z-index of 1. Both quads have `Color.Red * 0.5f`. Gets drawn first. The other object is the player with z-index 0. Gets drawn second

Because I want the player to move in between the quads, I have set `DepthStencilState` to  `DepthStencilState.Default;` but this provides the following image. The player's pixels get disregarded because there is an object in front of it.

I batch all my primitives into one big DrawUserPrimitive based on [this class](https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/blob/master/Primitives/PrimitiveBatch.cs). What is the best solution to this problem? Do I have to sort triangle based on z-index (and how would I do that; is it expensive?) or is there another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to do exactly what [that article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/02/18/depth-sorting-alpha-blended-objects.aspx) says. Here are the instructions listed as "The most common approach", updated for XNA 4:

1. Set `GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default`
2. Draw all opaque geometry
3. Set `GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead`
4. Sort alpha blended objects by distance from the camera, then draw them in order from back to front

If your transparent objects are more-or-less convex, then you don't need to sort triangles - just the objects themselves - as long as you use `RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise` (ie: backface culling, the default).

The reason that you must do this is that the depth buffer can only store a single value - which is that of the topmost pixel. There is no concept of drawing "under" that depth. The data that would be required to do that (the colours of the objects drawn above and below that Z-index, at that pixel) has already been blended into the final image and cannot be extracted.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I have to sort the objects. They are indeed more-or-less convex, though I think using culling won't help because my shapes are too basic and consist of too few triangles, and 99% of the time those triangles are only partially visible. I'll go for sorting, I still have to find out how (break up the red object in 2 for example), but I'll manage. Any tips or articles very welcome!

Comment: Even for a single translucent model (so: independently of sorting or Z-buffer), you need to do back-face culling to get a correct rendering result. If you don't, then then the back faces can be drawn over the top of the front faces (depending on triangle order and camera direction). Of course - this will only draw the front faces of the model, so if you want both the front and back sides to be visible (which will make it look more like a hollow object than a solid one), you must render in two passes (front-face culled, then back-face culled).

Comment: (Just to be clear - the back-face culling requirement is for 3D convex shapes - like a cube or a sphere. Not quads (it's a bit hard to tell what you're rendering in that screenshot). Basically it's a cheap way to sort the triangles on a per-model basis, without actually sorting them.)